# Unable to customize the time options using DateTimePicker library of MUI

Tags: localization, datetimepicker, mui-x

I am trying to set default time as 7:00AM on every date I pick using DateTimePicker. The only way I have been able to achieve it was by hardcoding the value when the user chooses new value. MY UI looks like this where by default the clock time is set to 12:00 AM. [image]

I tried the following workaround to set it to 7:00 AM which is getting set once user selects the date but the slider is scrolled down to 7:00 AM in the UI side and scrolling is seen. I want to set it at the top of the time so that the time options start from 7:00 AM and other options before 7:00 AM remains at the top of it.
my code block is

```
<DateTimePicker
  value={moment(timeSlotItem)}  //  (timeSlotItem: Date | null ) 
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    const defaultTime = '07:00:00'; // Set default time to 7:00 AM
    const formattedDate = newValue.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const newValueWithDefaultTime = moment(`${formattedDate} ${defaultTime}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    handleDateTimeChange(index, newValueWithDefaultTime);
  }}
/>
```

Is there any way I can customize the Time shown to my choice so that by default it sticks at 7:00 AM.